# How to use gitlab search criteria

Tags: git, gitlab

In gitlab's doc, there is [list projects API](http://doc.gitlab.com/ee/api/projects.html#list-projects),
however I wonder how to use the `search` field.

I've tried with `http://GITLAB_API/projects?search=QUERY&private_token=xxx`, and it successfully returned projects those contain `QUERY` in their names, but I want to know if there is advanced search criteria available? For example, I want to get projects under certain namespace, is it possible to filter those projects through this api? Or any api else?

Thank you!

Comment: found anything so far?

Answer (score 7):

It appears to search for projects that have a name, path, namespace, or description that match your query string. Sadly, it doesn't appear to be anything fancier.

Tracing the source code of 8.3 stable: [lib/api/projects.rb](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/8-3-stable/lib/api/projects.rb#L24) calls a `filter_projects` helper in [lib/api/helpers.rb](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/8-3-stable/lib/api/helpers.rb#L259) which calls `search` in [app/models/project.rb](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/8-3-stable/app/models/project.rb#L243).